# extraneous input 'CREATE' expecting {<EOF>, ';'}

Tags: apache-spark-sql

Try to run the query in spark hadoop and got error of `extraneous input 'CREATE' expecting {<EOF>, ';'}` even though I could run the query in adhoc query book.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pinnability_calibration_reporting.py", line 67, in <module>
    run()
  File "pinnability_calibration_reporting.py", line 63, in run
    spark_session.sql(query)
  File "/data/nvme2n1/nm-local-dir/usercache/appcache/application_1699031624646_295484/container_e82_1699031624646_295484_01_000015/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 723, in sql
  File "/data/nvme2n1/nm-local-dir/usercache/appcache/application_1699031624646_295484/container_e82_1699031624646_295484_01_000015/py4j-0.10.9.2-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1309, in __call__
  File "/data/nvme2n1/nm-local-dir/usercache/appcache/application_1699031624646_295484/container_e82_1699031624646_295484_01_000015/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 117, in deco
pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException: 
extraneous input 'CREATE' expecting {<EOF>, ';'}(line 3, pos 8)

== SQL ==

        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pinnability.calibration_summary_reporting_v2_2023_12_06;
        CREATE TABLE pinnability.calibration_summary_reporting_v2_2023_12_06 (
--------^^^
            
            
            SELECT dt, DECODE(`PASSED_IN_DATA/pinnability__context__modelId`, 'utf-8') AS model_id,
                'is_repin' AS head_name,
                AVG(`ATTACHED_DATA/pinnability__online_pin__calibratedRepinScore`) AS avg_score,
                COUNT_IF(`LABEL/is_repin` = TRUE) AS positives,
                COUNT(*) AS impressions,
                CAST(COUNT_IF(`LABEL/is_repin` = TRUE) AS DOUBLE) / CAST(COUNT(*) AS DOUBLE) AS empirical_rate,
                AVG(`ATTACHED_DATA/pinnability__online_pin__calibratedRepinScore`)/(CAST(COUNT_IF(`LABEL/is_repin` = TRUE) AS DOUBLE) / CAST(COUNT(*) AS DOUBLE)) AS calibration
            FROM pinnability.calibrationlabelswithfeatures
            WHERE
                `ATTACHED_DATA/pinnability__online_pin__calibratedRepinScore` IS NOT NULL
                AND dt = '2023-12-06'
            GROUP BY 1, 2
            
            
                UNION ALL
            
            SELECT dt, DECODE(`PASSED_IN_DATA/pinnability__context__modelId`, 'utf-8') AS model_id,
                'is_click' AS head_name,
                AVG(`ATTACHED_DATA/pinnability__online_pin__calibratedClickScore`) AS avg_score,
                COUNT_IF(`LABEL/is_click` = TRUE) AS positives,
                COUNT(*) AS impressions,
                CAST(COUNT_IF(`LABEL/is_click` = TRUE) AS DOUBLE) / CAST(COUNT(*) AS DOUBLE) AS empirical_rate,
                AVG(`ATTACHED_DATA/pinnability__online_pin__calibratedClickScore`)/(CAST(COUNT_IF(`LABEL/is_click` = TRUE) AS DOUBLE) / CAST(COUNT(*) AS DOUBLE)) AS calibration
            FROM pinnability.calibrationlabelswithfeatures
            WHERE
                `ATTACHED_DATA/pinnability__online_pin__calibratedClickScore` IS NOT NULL
                AND dt = '2023-12-06'
            GROUP BY 1, 2
            
            
                UNION ALL
            
            SELECT dt, DECODE(`PASSED_IN_DATA/pinnability__context__modelId`, 'utf-8') AS model_id,
                'is_longclick' AS head_name,
                AVG(`ATTACHED_DATA/pinnability__online_pin__calibratedLongClickScore`) AS avg_score,
                COUNT_IF(`LABEL/is_longclick` = TRUE) AS positives,
                COUNT(*) AS impressions,
                CAST(COUNT_IF(`LABEL/is_longclick` = TRUE) AS DOUBLE) / CAST(COUNT(*) AS DOUBLE) AS empirical_rate,
                AVG(`ATTACHED_DATA/pinnability__online_pin__calibratedLongClickScore`)/(CAST(COUNT_IF(`LABEL/is_longclick` = TRUE) AS DOUBLE) / CAST(COUNT(*) AS DOUBLE)) AS calibration
            FROM pinnability.calibrationlabelswithfeatures
            WHERE
                `ATTACHED_DATA/pinnability__online_pin__calibratedLongClickScore` IS NOT NULL
                AND dt = '2023-12-06'
            GROUP BY 1, 2
            
            
                UNION ALL
            
            SELECT dt, DECODE(`PASSED_IN_DATA/pinnability__context__modelId`, 'utf-8') AS model_id,
                'is_closeup' AS head_name,
                AVG(`ATTACHED_DATA/pinnability__online_pin__calibratedCloseupScore`) AS avg_score,
                COUNT_IF(`LABEL/is_closeup` = TRUE) AS positives,
                COUNT(*) AS impressions,
                CAST(COUNT_IF(`LABEL/is_closeup` = TRUE) AS DOUBLE) / CAST(COUNT(*) AS DOUBLE) AS empirical_rate,
                AVG(`ATTACHED_DATA/pinnability__online_pin__calibratedCloseupScore`)/(CAST(COUNT_IF(`LABEL/is_closeup` = TRUE) AS DOUBLE) / CAST(COUNT(*) AS DOUBLE)) AS calibration
            FROM pinnability.calibrationlabelswithfeatures
            WHERE
                `ATTACHED_DATA/pinnability__online_pin__calibratedCloseupScore` IS NOT NULL
                AND dt = '2023-12-06'
            GROUP BY 1, 2
            
            
                UNION ALL
            
            SELECT dt, DECODE(`PASSED_IN_DATA/pinnability__context__modelId`, 'utf-8') AS model_id,
                'is_10sfsv' AS head_name,
                AVG(`ATTACHED_DATA/pinnability__online_pin__calibratedVideo10secScore`) AS avg_score,
                COUNT_IF(`LABEL/is_10sfsv` = TRUE) AS positives,
                COUNT(*) AS impressions,
                CAST(COUNT_IF(`LABEL/is_10sfsv` = TRUE) AS DOUBLE) / CAST(COUNT(*) AS DOUBLE) AS empirical_rate,
                AVG(`ATTACHED_DATA/pinnability__online_pin__calibratedVideo10secScore`)/(CAST(COUNT_IF(`LABEL/is_10sfsv` = TRUE) AS DOUBLE) / CAST(COUNT(*) AS DOUBLE)) AS calibration
            FROM pinnability.calibrationlabelswithfeatures
            WHERE
                `ATTACHED_DATA/pinnability__online_pin__calibratedVideo10secScore` IS NOT NULL
                AND dt = '2023-12-06'
            GROUP BY 1, 2
            
            
                UNION ALL
            
            SELECT dt, DECODE(`PASSED_IN_DATA/pinnability__context__modelId`, 'utf-8') AS model_id,
                'is_hide' AS head_name,
                AVG(`ATTACHED_DATA/pinnability__online_pin__calibratedHideScore`) AS avg_score,
                COUNT_IF(`LABEL/is_hide` = TRUE) AS positives,
                COUNT(*) AS impressions,
                CAST(COUNT_IF(`LABEL/is_hide` = TRUE) AS DOUBLE) / CAST(COUNT(*) AS DOUBLE) AS empirical_rate,
                AVG(`ATTACHED_DATA/pinnability__online_pin__calibratedHideScore`)/(CAST(COUNT_IF(`LABEL/is_hide` = TRUE) AS DOUBLE) / CAST(COUNT(*) AS DOUBLE)) AS calibration
            FROM pinnability.calibrationlabelswithfeatures
            WHERE
                `ATTACHED_DATA/pinnability__online_pin__calibratedHideScore` IS NOT NULL
                AND dt = '2023-12-06'
            GROUP BY 1, 2
            
            
                UNION ALL
            
            SELECT dt, DECODE(`PASSED_IN_DATA/pinnability__context__modelId`, 'utf-8') AS model_id,
                'is_short_click_2s' AS head_name,
                AVG(`ATTACHED_DATA/pinnability__online_pin__calibratedShortClickScore`) AS avg_score,
                COUNT_IF(`LABEL/is_short_click_2s` = TRUE) AS positives,
                COUNT(*) AS impressions,
                CAST(COUNT_IF(`LABEL/is_short_click_2s` = TRUE) AS DOUBLE) / CAST(COUNT(*) AS DOUBLE) AS empirical_rate,
                AVG(`ATTACHED_DATA/pinnability__online_pin__calibratedShortClickScore`)/(CAST(COUNT_IF(`LABEL/is_short_click_2s` = TRUE) AS DOUBLE) / CAST(COUNT(*) AS DOUBLE)) AS calibration
            FROM pinnability.calibrationlabelswithfeatures
            WHERE
                `ATTACHED_DATA/pinnability__online_pin__calibratedShortClickScore` IS NOT NULL
                AND dt = '2023-12-06'
            GROUP BY 1, 2
            
            
                UNION ALL
            
            SELECT dt, DECODE(`PASSED_IN_DATA/pinnability__context__modelId`, 'utf-8') AS model_id,
                'is_p2p_impression' AS head_name,
                AVG(`ATTACHED_DATA/pinnability__online_pin__calibratedP2PImpressionScore`) AS avg_score,
                COUNT_IF(`LABEL/is_p2p_impression` = TRUE) AS positives,
                COUNT(*) AS impressions,
                CAST(COUNT_IF(`LABEL/is_p2p_impression` = TRUE) AS DOUBLE) / CAST(COUNT(*) AS DOUBLE) AS empirical_rate,
                AVG(`ATTACHED_DATA/pinnability__online_pin__calibratedP2PImpressionScore`)/(CAST(COUNT_IF(`LABEL/is_p2p_impression` = TRUE) AS DOUBLE) / CAST(COUNT(*) AS DOUBLE)) AS calibration
            FROM pinnability.calibrationlabelswithfeatures
            WHERE
                `ATTACHED_DATA/pinnability__online_pin__calibratedP2PImpressionScore` IS NOT NULL
                AND dt = '2023-12-06'
            GROUP BY 1, 2
            
        );
```